# Installshield limited edition - Application installation error

Tags: c#, installshield, installshield-le

I'm using `InstallShield Limited Edition` for my C# project in visual studio 2013.
My solution includes eight projects.

If I initially create a new InstallShield project for the entire solution and generate the install files everything works fine. I can install my application and run it.
After that I make any change in one of my projects, rebuild the entire solution and install the new created InstallShield installation file. That's where my problem starts.

The installation works fine, but my application does not start anymore.

Immediately after starting the application, it throws an exception. 
If I delete the entire InstallShield project in my solution and create a new one again everything works fine again. (Installation + application).

The exception/error I get is the following:

> Problem signature: 
>   Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
>   Problem Signature 01:   controller.exe
>   Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.0
>   Problem Signature 03:   55dcae6a
>   Problem Signature 04:   PresentationFramework
>   Problem Signature 05:   4.0.30319.18408
>   Problem Signature 06:   52312f13
>   Problem Signature 07:   9d1
>   Problem Signature 08:   f
>   Problem Signature 09:   System.IO.FileLoadException
>   OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
>   Locale ID:  18441
>   Additional Information 1:   dbaa
>   Additional Information 2:   dbaabd7b5abf4a09daa2dcf53831b2b4
>   Additional Information 3:   c62a 
>   Additional Information 4:   c62aad58d3308b9118d0dd699a78f759

So the problem shouldn't be my application itself. It seems that it is related to the InstallShield project.

Any change/build in my project after creating the initial InstallShield project in my solution triggers this error.

Is there any parameter or whatever that I have to consider in the InstallShield project?

Comment: Never had any problems like this. I have used InstallShield a lot over the years. Can you update the question with more info about the Exception when you try to run your application? I believe that the problem may be missing files that your program need.

Comment: @togocoder: Yes it is a FileLoadException. But i have no idea why this only happens afer a rebuilt

Comment: "PresentationFramework", i looks like a WPF program? - Are you having any images in you program, like PNG, JPG files that you refer to in XAML ?

Comment: Yes its a WPF application and i have jpg files managed in a ResourceDictionary in XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the WPF program is failing with FileLoadException, is the way JPG, PNG files are compiled. The Build Action is not correct.

In my project I have a folder called "Resources", in this folder I add all the JPG, PNG files I need to show in my XAML.
Every JPG or PNG file has

> "Build Action" set to "Resource"
>
> "Copy to Output Directory" set to "Do not copy".

[image]

In my XAML I can then refer to a JPG, like:

```
<Image Source="/Resources/Phonebook36.jpg" />
```

[image]